# $watch is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I have angular directive that looks like this

```
    app.directive('paymentsTable', ['$watch', function($watch) {
    return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'EACM',
      templateUrl: '../views/paymentTable.html',
      link: function(elem, attr, scope) {

      console.log(elem.$parent.payments); // array

      scope.$watch(function(elem) { return elem.$parent.payments }, function(value, oldValue) {

      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

It gives me

> angular.js:13920Error: [$injector:unpr]

When I rewrite first line like this

```
app.directive('paymentsTable', [ function() {
```

It gives me another error

> angular.js:13920TypeError: o.$watch is not a function

I also use uglify. So, my question is: what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$watch` function is part of `scope` that is handed to you in the `link` method, therefore there is no need to inject it. The reason you get the second error is the order of the `link` arguments. Try it like this:

```
 app.directive('paymentsTable', function() { // no need for injection
    return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'EACM',
      templateUrl: '../views/paymentTable.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) { // The correct arguments order

      console.log(elem.$parent.payments); 

      scope.$watch(function(elem) { return elem.$parent.payments }, function(value, oldValue) {

      });
    }
  };
});
```